# Get Data From wp_sitemeta for Multisite network

Tags: custom-field, multisite, meta-query, options

I have a multisite network with around 30 sites on it.

In the `wp_sitemeta` table, there are some options the previous dev had set (one of which is 'template_color').

So in the `wp_sitemeta` table, there is a `site_id` with a `meta_key` of 'template_color', and a `meta_value` of the hex value of the color.

I've written the following:

```
    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
            switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
            //do things
            $value = get_site_option( 'template_color', 'not available' );
            echo $value;
            restore_current_blog();

    }
```

But `$value` just shows 'not available' for each site.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for this is contradictory, but I believe wp_sitemeta is meant to only store information for sites in the wp_sites table, which only stores the main site in a network. It would make more sense to store each site's template_color in their individual wp_[BLOGID]_options tables.

However, keeping the data as-is, you may be able to use the following instead of get_site_option:

```
get_network_option( $site->blog_id, 'template_color', 'not_available' )
```

Comment: The 1st parameter in [`get_network_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_network_option/) is the `$network_id`, not the `$blog_id`, so unfortunately I don't think this will work.

Comment: I agree it's not supposed to work, but the reason it would is because the previous dev was storing the subsites' blog IDs in a database column that WP expects the network ID to be stored in. The get_site_option function is just a wrapper of get_network_option. I got it to work after manually adding a row in the wp_sitemeta table. Still, it's a hack, and I'd recommend moving the template_color values to individual wp_options tables.

Comment: What I forgot is that this is a multi-network, multi-site install. get_network_option() is what I needed and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Please [update your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/304147/edit) to include the multi-network aspect—it'll help others who might be having a similar problem.